# Line graph for one variable in r, how to color?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

So I thought this was going to be simple using the following:

```
df <- structure(list(time_bin = c("00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
"06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"), count = c(33L, 35L, 
35L, 27L, 24L, 22L, 47L, 73L, 84L, 90L, 131L, 122L, 91L, 97L, 
78L, 70L, 56L, 50L, 54L, 37L, 40L, 25L, 24L, 31L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And using the following code, get a plot with the color specified below. However this still does not plot...

```
ggplot(time_bin_counts, aes(y=count, x=as.factor(time_bin), color = "mediumpurple2"  )) +
  geom_line() +
 labs(x = "Day of the Week", y = "Injury", fill = "") +
  lims(y = c(0,150)) +
  theme_hc() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=count, x=as.factor(time_bin),group=1 )) +
  geom_line(color = "mediumpurple2") +
  labs(x = "Day of the Week", y = "Injury", fill = "") +
  lims(y = c(0,150)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello again Duck, but what about my data isn't working as is? Is the group argument required for data like this?

Comment: @JohnThomas If you have only one var, you can use `group=1` but if you wish more lines you should have other variable for grouping in your dataframe. Also same variable could be used for color and then you can add the colors you want with `scale_color_manual()`. Let me know if that helped :)